# Material.io Tabs: where to put the tab content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I'm trying to use material.io tabs in a project, anyway the html structure is not well documented:

https://material.io/components/tabs/web#design-api-documentation

```
<div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
  <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
    <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">
        <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
          <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">favorite</span>
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Favorites</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where am i supposed to put the tab body content? It seems they shows only how to build a tab bar but not the whole functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you should make the tab bars in a div then content in another div additionally use javascript to specify when content should change. I hope this answer helped. I think my answer must not be very clear but when you go through the code you will find what I mean

```html
<div class="svelte4" style="flex:1;" id="tim">
     <div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist" style="background-color:rgb(34, 34, 34);">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
        <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
          <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">
    
            <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">1</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
    
    
    
            <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">2</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
    
    
            <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">3</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
    
    
          
    
    
    
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="content content--active">
    <p>1</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
    <p>2</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content"> 
    <p>3</p>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

```js
var tabBar = new mdc.tabBar.MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('.mdc-tab-bar'));
var contentEls = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

tabBar.listen('MDCTabBar:activated', function (event) {
  // Hide currently-active content
  document.querySelector('.content--active').classList.remove('content--active');
  // Show content for newly-activated tab
  contentEls[event.detail.index].classList.add('content--active');
});
```